# Replace -infinty value and infinity value to max and min of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe where I have infinte and -infinite value, I would like to replace it with max and min value of the data frame, I am able to replace for infinte value to max but not able to do the same for
-infite value

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
a = float('Inf')
b = float('-Inf')
v = [1,2,5,a,b,10,5,a,5,100,2,b,b]  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_A': v})
```

Replace infinte value to max value

```
df['Col_A'].replace([np.inf],max(df['Col_A'].replace(np.inf, 
np.nan)),inplace=True)
```

**Snippet of the df**

[image]

**I want to replace the inf value to 100 as that is the max value and -inf with 1 as that is the min value if possible in one logic and the values should not be hardcoded**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost there:

```
df['Col_A'].replace([-np.inf],min(df['Col_A'].replace(-np.inf, 
np.nan)),inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks QPeiran, I was using np.-inf

Answer (score 0):

Min/Max can return inf values as min/max, so you can filter out and then replace:

```
v1 = df.loc[~df['Col_A'].isin([np.inf,-np.inf]),'Col_A'].max()
v2 = df.loc[~df['Col_A'].isin([np.inf,-np.inf]),'Col_A'].min()
df['Col_A'] = df['Col_A'].replace([np.inf,-np.inf], [v1,v2])
df
```